# Using $function to run a javascript function is not working in mongosh, it hangs

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I’m trying to use a function in order to parse a json format field in a collection. But it seems that I’m missing some previous steps in order to do so, if I run a simple aggregation like this:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
    { 
      $addFields: {
        fromFunction: {
          $function: {
            body: "function(){return 'hello'}",
            args: [], 
            lang: 'js'
          }
        }
       }
     }
  ])
```

nothing happens, the collection is not created ( Reference: How to Use Custom Aggregation Expressions in MongoDB 4.4 | MongoDB 1).

Somebody suggested this other syntax, but the query hangs (similar behaviour when using the JSON.parse inside the function):

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    '$addFields': {
      fromFunction: { '$function': { body: function(){return 'hello'}, args: [], lang: 'js' } }
    }
  }
])
```

Do I need to install any driver or package, or setup the shell in order to run such javascript function? I’m using MongoDB Compass Shell. Versions: MongoDB Compass 1.36.4, mongoDB 6.0.6

Comment: `aggregate` **queries** a collection, it does not create any collection (unless you use stage `$out` or `$merge`).

Comment: Did you set `enableJavascript: false`?

Comment: You are right, Wernfried, I didn't documment the complete code, only part of it. Anyway, I found the reason why the function hangs, it seems to be a bug of the Compass shell, I executed the function in a standalone mongo shell and now it doesn't hang but finishes and a collection is created. Now I have a different problem but I will open a new topic. Thanks for reading